# Where does the message head after a Patterns.ask timeout?

Tags: java, akka, future

Been recently experiencing some timeouts with **scala.concurrent.Future** objects created awaiting processing within an Akka actor and I was wondering how to handle those timeout'd events. Are they really lost? Are they retried and preserved in memory or how does it work?

To put a bit of context, the code goes the following.

```
List<Future<MyMessage>> futureMessageList = plainMessages.stream()
    .map(this::toFuture)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());    

Futures.sequence(futureMessageList, ExecutionContexts.global())
                .onComplete(new OnComplete<Iterable<MyMessage>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Throwable throwable, Iterable<MyMessage> messages) {
                        ... // iterate futureMessageList list
```

Within the `onComplete` an iteration over `futureMessageList` takes place, which is basically composed of `Future` objects which encapsulate `MyMessage`.

However, **the function `toFuture` does a `Patterns.ask()` with a given dispatcher and that seems to be taking more than the timeout I sent (60 seconds)**. Take into account that the response times depend on an underlying system which may be under high load or without the fastest network depending on the environment it runs.

`Future<MyMessage> message = Patterns.ask(actorSystem.getSampleDispatcher(), msg, TIMEOUT_60_SECS)`

So my question is, after the `onComplete` throws the following exception due to the Future not being processed in time...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.package.Clazz.onComplete(Clazz.java:4)
    at my.package.Clazz$1.onComplete(Clazz.java:5)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:256)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:186)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:183)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run$$$capture(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
```

Are those `MyMessage` objs saved within memory and retried afterwards? Should I somehow handle the exception and handle those timeout'd messages with an in-memory list or how should I workaround this?

Comment: That doesn't look like a timeout exception. You have something else going on there.

Comment: I thought it wasn't at first @texasbruce , happens at times. However, if I set that timeout to, let's say, 1ms, it does always crash with the exact same message. I want to think that the list of futures when being iterated, trigger the timeout and the NullPointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ask` times out from not getting a reply it completes the `Future` (or `CompletionStage`) with a failure. The message may still be somewhere being processed and if there is a response it will end up in dead letters (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#dead-letters). Other scenarios where the timeout could hit are if the actor has stopped or crashed processing the message, the request or response got lost (not likely unless the responding actor is remote).

`Future.sequence` will either complete successfully when all futures passed to it has completed successfully or fail if any of them fails.

This means that if any of the asks time out you will get `null` as the messages parameter and the exception from the first failing future as the `throwable` parameter in your `onComplete` callback.

If you rather would like to get a partial list of results, each being either a successful value or an exception. You can do that with with the help of recover on each future before passing them to `Future.sequence`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a valuable response, so good to receive feedback from an official Akka dev :)